# Why EF6 allocate memory for some DbSets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I have a simple dbcontext, It has three set in it.
When I debug it using Windbg to see what object is live i see some dbset.

So, My question is why some dbset is in heap?

Here is my code:

```
public class Delivery
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() : base("db") { }

    public DbSet<Delivery> DeliveryMethods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new TestContext())
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Windbg Command: !dumpheap -type live
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some sort of weird stuff with naming entity.

If your entity name contains "delive", It will allocate memory.

I don't know if it is a bug or what, change your entity name (Delivery) and allocation will go away.

Comment: actually it has problem with "live".

Answer (score 1):

The base DbContext class initializes (via reflection) any DbSet properties.
See [DbContext with DbSet properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/dbsets#dbcontext-with-dbset-properties) in the documentation

> In addition, DbContext will automatically call the setter for each of these properties to set an instance of the appropriate DbSet.

You never need to actually create a DbSet yourself.